# Color of div based on parent element's class

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the first cell of each row contains a div which spans the entire row. I want the background of each div to be a different color based on the class of the containing row. Is this possible?

Something along the lines of:

```
tr.even div.myDivClass{
    background-color: red;
}
tr.odd div.myDivClass{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Here is simplified version of the table:

```
<table>
    <tr class="even">
        <td colspan="14">
            <div class="myDivClass"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="14">
            <div class="myDivClass"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <td colspan="14">
            <div class="myDivClass"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
        <td colspan="14">
            <div class="myDivClass"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work to me as-is.

Comment: I simplified a lot from my actual application. Didn't try the simplified version... wow, it works.... then I must be doing something wrong in my actual page. Thanks

Comment: You can try to right click on the element and select "Inspect Element".  This should point to the exact class in your page that is causing a different color than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want alternate colors (which is what your code is doing), you could simply use the following without defining any classes:

`tr:nth-of-type(even)  {
    background-color: red;
    }
tr:nth-of-type(odd)  {
    background-color: green;
    }`

If you want it to be 'any' color, then I don't see a problem with your code.